# adding common names in the column - awk

Tags: awk

Is it possible to print unique names in 1st column by adding the names in the 2nd column like below ? thanx in advance!

input

```
tony  singapore
johnny  germany
johnny  singapore
```

output

```
tony  singapore
johnny  germany;singapore
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one-liner:

```
awk '{a[$1]=$1 in a?a[$1]";"$2:$2}END{for(x in a)print x, a[x]}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '{name2vals[$1] = name2vals[$1] sep[$1] $2; sep[$1] = ";"} END { for (name in name2vals) print name, name2vals[name]}' file
johnny germany;singapore
tony singapore
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a cryptic sed variant:

#### Content of script.sed

```
$ cat script.sed 
:a                        # Create a label called loop
$!N                       # If not last line, append the line to pattern space
s/^(([^ ]+ ).*)\n\2/\1;/  # If first column is same append second column to it separated by ;
ta                        # If the last substitution was successful loop back
P                         # Print up to the first \n of the current pattern space
D                         # Delete from current pattern space, up to the \n character
```

#### Execution:

```
$ cat file
tony  singapore
johnny  germany
johnny  singapore

$ sed -rf script.sed file
tony  singapore
johnny  germany; singapore
```